# Blueimp Gallery inside Boostrap Modal not vertical aligned properly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, lightbox, blueimp

I have a modal window that shows a few data that also has Images which open in Blueimp gallery. The problem I have is, when the image is opened in BlueImp gallery, the image is not vertically aligned in the middle of the screen. Its either to the bottom or to the top and it depends on where I have scrolled in the modal window. I need to go to the middle of the modal window and open the gallery in which case the Lightbox looks centered. This issue doesnt happen when blueimp is used directly in the page without a modal. It appears the blueimp gallery's lightbox is centered to the whole modal height instead of the viewport height. How can I override that for blueimp inside modal windows only? Is there a css fix or js fix to override this when blueimp is used in boostrap modals?

Here is a sample of my set-up:

```
<div uib-modal-window="modal-window" class="modal fade" role="dialog" size="xl" index="0" animate="animate" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + $$topModalIndex*10, display: 'block'}" tabindex="-1" uib-modal-animation-class="fade" modal-in-class="in" modal-animation="true" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div class="modal-content" uib-modal-transclude="">
        <div class="lightBoxGallery">
            <a ng-repeat="image in vm.ngModel" ng-href="{{::vm.imageurl(image.name)}}" data-gallery="">
                <img ng-src="{{::vm.getImage(image.name)}}" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail animated fadeIn">
            </a>
            <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
                    <div class="slides"></div>
                    <h3 class="title"></h3>
                    <a class="prev">‹</a>
                    <a class="next">›</a>
                    <a class="close">×</a>
                    <a class="play-pause"></a>
                    <ol class="indicator"></ol> </div>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My set-up: Angular 1.5 + Bootstrap 3 + Bootstrap UI + BlueImp Gallery

**UPDATE:**

The problem I am having here is, my Bootstrap Modal window has `overflow-y` as scrollable and it has a fixed positioning:

```
.modal-open .modal {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.modal {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    outline: 0;
}
```

And when the `blueimp-gallery` is opened, as a child div with fixed position, it is positioning the Div to the center of the parent's fixed position instead of center of the viewport:

```
.blueimp-gallery {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    direction: ltr;
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    touch-action: none;
}
```

The `blueimp-gallery` is aligning to the middle, but I dont want it aligning to the middle of parent (modal) div. I want it aligned to the middle of viewport. For example, in my laptop, my modal has a height of 2000px where as my viewport height is a lot less like 860px. That is why the gallery lightbox is opening either to the top or bottom of the viewport unless the user is right in the middle of the modal window. If I place the `blueimp-gallery` directly in the body without the modal window, I dont have this issue. But in this use case, I have to place the `blueimp-gallery` inside a Modal window that has variable height depending on the dynamic content loaded in it.

I am still stuck on this, does anyone have a suggestion to this problem please?

Comment: hi im back :) so say you have the lightboxgallary in the middle. and when its oppened the blueimp is in te center of the lightboxgallary? or where do you want them to be? maybe adding screenshots with the problem and the result u want then you get more reactions to this.

Comment: hi @H.Brendan Thanks for coming back. Yes, you are right. When the image opens with in blueimp gallery it is in the middle of the modal. I want the gallery to be displayed in the middle of the viewport instead of middle of the modal. The problem is, I display the images at the bottom of the information displayed inside the modal and the modal height is like 2000px. So when the image is opened in blueimp lightbox which is centred to the modal, the opened lightbox is not viewable from the location its clicked from. Its even more difficult in Mobile.

Comment: The only option I can think of is its restrict the modal height by changing `.modal-open .modal` class to `overflow-y: hidden;` and then setting `overflow:scroll` for the the div inside the modal so the height of the modal stays the same as the viewport in which case the height of the blueimp will be the same. But this is not good UI in my use case since the div inside doesnt flow well due to scroll.

Comment: this is just a random thought that came up in me. but cant you try to give the div it should open in an ID and fiddle arround with some javascript so the box that has to be shown will be put in the div with that specific ID ? im almost sure its possible im not so sure if this is very easy or not.

Comment: I didn't do exactly that but I tried adding a javascript to the blueimp gallery `isopened` event and `isclosed` event that changes the css position property of the modal window when the lightbox is opened and closed so the modal's fixed position doesnt affect the `.blueimp-gallery` fixed position. But that didint work because the `isopened` event is triggered for every change in gallery and even during gallery close so this doesnt work.

Comment: Another method I tried was, I added the css `transform: translate3d(0,0,0); overflow:hidden;` to the image wrapper. This worked in some sense because the modal opened inside the wrapper but doesnt work in my case since the image wrapper has a height of only 200px since it displays thumbnails only. Therefore, the gallery lightbox gets fit inside this 200px height box.

Comment: Last method I tried was force the gallery to open in fullscreen using javascript. But when the fullscreen is closed by esc, the lighbox doesnt close and the image is still shown misplaced somewhere in the modal like my initial issue. Also opening the image in fullscreen each time wasnt a good ui as well.

Comment: Well u tried allot thats for sure. but the fullscreen method was something i thougt about also but well ye. if its not ui friendly thats a problem. but still i guess this is the quickest and dirtiest fix for this problem. you can try that one again and find out ho to close it uppon pressing the ESC key

Comment: sure. I will give it another crack at it tonight. Fingers crossed.

Comment: exactly haha good luck. ill be off for today.

Comment: hi @H.Brendan I was finally able to find a solution that works. I added a jquery code that pulls the `#blueimp-gallery` element out of the modal window and adds it as a direct child of the body element. This hack seems to do the trick since the gallery lightbox now respects the viewport height instead of using the Modal window's height. Thank you so much for guiding me throughout my trouble. I am happy to award you the bounty for your kind assistance. Thank you indeed.

Comment: Haha thank you verry much for the bounty glad i could help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I was able to resolve this issue was to pull the `"#blueimp-gallery"` element out of the Modal Window and then insert it again as a direct child of the `body` element. Using Jquery, I added this code that fixed the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#blueimp-gallery").prependTo($("body"));
});
```

Now, after the above code, the BlueImp Gallery's fixed position is relative to the body element and therefore the height is that of the viewport. The Modal height no longer affects the BlueImp Gallery's height since it is now placed as a direct child of `body` element.

Comment: You made my afternoon ;)

Comment: Works like a charm. now i understand that the lightBoxGallery is the `gallery` , and it will showed in #blueimp-gallery. am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to put the blueimp in a div with the class `row` and then another div with the class `col-md-6` not 100% sure but it should be alligned in the middle then.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery vcenter ">
         ...
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Edit tried it it has to have container tag above it to.

most likely this is not the sollution to getting it to the center vertically but this is worth a try i guess

ADDITION

```
.vcenter {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float: none;
}
```

create a costum tag add it in a css file and call on it.

Comment: Thank you @H.Brendan. I will give it a try now.

Comment: I tried adding `container`, `row` and `col-md-6` around `blueimp-gallery` and the `.vcenter` styles and the positioning. Its similar to the previous issue in the sense that, lets say the images are placed at the bottom of the modal window and I click on the image without fully centering the image section, the blueimg-gallery will show the image at the bottom since the container is wrapper around there. (cont...)

Comment: However, its slightly better than before in the sense that atleast when clicking on the blueimp link while centering the images block, then it should show fine since the blueimp is now centered to the img block and not the whole modal. I will now test that from mobile and see. This is probably the best work around for this, isint it.

Comment: Sorry, it didint work once I added to live code. When the `#blueimp-gallery` is wrapped with the container and row divs, the img anchor is no longer clickable. it only works when `#blueimp-gallery`  is directly placed after the `<a>` tag. I also tried wrapping the entire images section inside the containers, then in that case the modal is no longer scrollable.

Comment: try moving the row divs etc up some rows. like say above  <div class="lightBoxGallery"> or somethnig

Comment: yeah,  I tried that. But the modal window is not scrollable and the gallery images are not clickable.

Comment: ah ok. well im in the dark on this one then. sorry.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for your input though. I appreciate that.